# What can I do In below , I am stuck?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am woking on project called team recommendation for cricket . In which we will take as external required features and also players past profile for training the system . But now I am stuck while training as I have got player's profile as a array , so how do I use regression on it ?? Can we pass such array in regression ? I no please suggest me briefly what I should do ??

```
Player1                                  Player2                country1 country2             country2                                                                                               
[153.0, 102.0, 33.0]                [153.0, 102.0, 33.0]           0      1                      0
```

SO as shown above , each array defines players profile , for example sake this array are only of size 3 , but in dataset they are of size 27 long . Now when I pass them as it is in regression I am getting  "string cannot be converted to float exception" ad they are gettinginputted as string in regression . What should I do , please help me :/

What have been tried:

```
df=pd.read_csv(csv_path)
funtional_headers=json.loads(open('./meta/funtional_headers.json','r').read())
player_header=json.loads(open('./meta/player_headers.json','r').read())`
```

```
X=df.loc[:,funtional_headers]
Y=df.loc[:,players_headers]`
```

```
print(Y.iloc[0:1]['Player1'][0])
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3)
clf_RF_Rice=RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=30,random_state=1)`
```

```
scores=cross_val_score(clf_RF_Rice,X,Y,cv=5)
clf_RF_Rice.fit(X_train,Y_train)
clf_RF_Rice.score(X_test,Y_test)
```

> VALUE ERROR:Could not turn string into float

[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLjVz.png)

Comment: Without posting code and the concrete error message, nobody can help you with your problem.

Comment: Add the code, which you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO; in addition to the advice offered above, please take a minute to see why [an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) (same for an image of your [exception](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)).

Answer (score 0):

No, it can not an array. It needs to be a matrix/dataframe with only one number, whether you turn that array into a single number or a matrix/dataframe.